# How to close access to instance to all except load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I have a web application (nginx + go, by docker) on my ec2 instance. I need to add https. For this I created new certificate in ACM and load balancer(LB, https -> http). Then I added new record in Route53 for LB (for e.g. lb.example.com). Now, my app available by:

- https://lb.example.com (by lb)
- http://ec2_public_ip

I want that my app will available only by https://lb.example.com (by lb, through https). How can I do this ? I can't use server_name in nginx, because LB don't support it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your instance's security group you can allow only HTTPs and, instead of allowing the origin by IP address, use the ID of the ELB security group. This way only traffic coming from the ELB will be accepted by the instances.

See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/building-three-tier-architectures-with-security-groups/

Comment: You are great. Thank you!